# Switching drives while using IWidgets-fileselectionbox

Tags: user-interface, widget, tcl

I'm using IWidgets with Tcl and specifically, I'm using the 'fileselectionbox' widget.
Double-click the '..' takes me one level up in the directories hierarchy but I can't switch drives, as it stops at the root drive of the initial directory.
How can I switch drives?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you use `tk_getOpenFile` instead? That's the native dialog.

Comment: No, because I need to integrate only the 'fileselectionbox' into my customized dialog